# You are given a series of random points and asked to find a graph that fits them, how would you do it?

Tags: polynomials

If you were given a large series of random number pairs $(x,y)$ and asked to find a graph that fit all of them in the form of $y = Ax^Z + Bx^Y + Cx^W + \cdots $.  Fine by me if sins and coses and potentially other mathematically functions are thrown into the mix.

How would you do it?

I'm trying to find a problem that is tailored to be 'easily' solvable for a neural network and easily check-able once solved, but tricky to otherwise solve.  I'm thinking this might be a good one. Still a newbie when it comes to neural networks though.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Is there another easier way to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just sample randomly coefficients of the polynomial and then sample randomly $x$ values and calculate $y$ values?

Comment: As long as you're working with finitely many points, the Lagrange interpolation method will work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial. (That's not to say this is the most efficient way to solve this problem; it just works in principle.)

Comment: To expand on @neuguy's good comment, there are a few fairly straightforward (if computationally expensive!) ways to solve this; another would be setting up a system of many equations in many unknowns for the coefficients of the polynomial (one for each point). I don't know what's well-suited for neural networks though...

Comment: If fitting method doesn't have to be polynomial you could use: $$f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{y_i}{(x-x_i)^{2k}}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x-x_i)^{2k}}}$$ when $x \not = x_i$ $ \forall i$. Notice that $\lim_{x \to x_i}(f(x)) = y_i$

Comment: Lagrange interpolation will produce a polynomial that interpolates the given points exactly, but for large numbers of points the resulting function tends to be very bad numerically.  For better numerical behaviour you might look at splines or wavelets.